# How do I remove a "window.api.receive" in Electron and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I have an Electron app using the recommended setup from https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/ where access is given via `window.api.receive` and `window.api.send` to the preloader. However I need to use `window.api.receive` within my react component and my issue is don't know how to remove the "receive" when the component is unmounted.

From the react side of things I think i just need to add in the code in the use effect, but I don't know what code can be used to remove the `window.api.receive` that was added.

```
  // On Mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mount APP')
    window.api.receive("helpLine", (text, loading) => {
      // Things are done here
  })
  }, []);

  // on Unmount
  useEffect( () => () => {
    console.log("unmount App")
    // window.api.receive should be removed here
  }, [] );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, listener)` to remove the specified listener.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovelistenerchannel-listener